# Yii & insert hour into calendar

Tags: calendar, yii, yii-extensions

I am working on an application for my employers in Yii.

My idea is, that they must be able to enter how many hours they are working per day. So I want one simple calendar where they can enter hours and save it to the db.

I was looking for a similar extension, but I didn't find anything that suits my needs.

[Best thing I found is the extension flowing calendar](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/flowing-calendar/)

What would be the best approach to create something similar to my request?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that you can use any javascript library in Yii, you don't have to use Yii extensions exclusively. Yii comes with jQuery UI as standard, so if you are just looking for a calendar you could use [jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

If you want time pickers, check this [timepicker add on](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

Comment: Yes, I know that and I've been watching this jQuery UI datapicker. But after I think what is best way and great for users experience I think, this is easy input form. But here I have problem how can I insert 30 or 31 (depend of day of month) input form into db when user click Save.

Comment: So you are saying you want the user to type in the date? For the 30/31 you can use php's cal_days_in_month() function to get the last day in a specific month/year. Explain a bit more detailed what you want so I can help you

Comment: All users whit in group "employers" must type how many hours for each day did they worked. Example: 1.11. one man working 4 hours and they must insert 4 for 1.11. and so one...

Comment: So you just want to create a record which stores the amount of hours for a specific date, for a specific user?

Comment: And you are using a database for the users?

Comment: I use a LDAP for authentication. In database I have groups (where I edit access for users to different applications I have in Yii).